# Loading an attribute value without loading an entire entity

Tags: php, performance, optimization, magento, profiling

So I was writing a piece of functionality where I was getting the parent category ids of a category and wanted to get the url_key of one of the parents in Magento. I wanted to do this without having to load the category and found this method `getAttributeRawValue`, which can be found here `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Abstract.php`. Basically it seems unnecessary  to load a whole entity then to just get the attribute value associated to that entity id.

It gets me what I need, but I am wondering if it is all that much better then loading the category and getting the attribute. Is loading the category essentially doing the same thing but doing it for every attribute?

Comment: Can you post the full code snippet so we can see the context for the call?

Comment: Won't loading the raw value be avoiding any overrides? First there is the category model's `_afterLoad` method and then possibly a custom getter. I haven't even checked for related events. These behaviours might be altered by third party extensions without you knowing. I believe the correct action would be to use the full model approach then cache your results.

Comment: but if its just getting a url_key or like name of a category it really wouldn't matter about any type of overrides right? I mean, a url_key is a url_key. all I am using it for is to put it on the body tag for a classname.

Comment: you're probably right, but @clockworkgeek's point still stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought would be to use the inbuilt Varien Profiler to test it quantitatively.  It's an underutilized by very useful trick.

Basically, you need to turn on Profiling in the Admin (System>Config>Advanced>Developer>Debug>Profiler) and then insert the start/stop instructions with a unique string either side of the code that you want to profile.  e.g.

```
Varien_Profiler::start('__CATEGORY_URL_KEY_RETURN__');
....
your code here
....
Varien_Profiler::stop('__CATEGORY_URL_KEY_RETURN__');
```

Load the page in your browser and you will see the Profiler output at the base.

Enjoy!